# Use SQL or python to check set membership?

Tags: python, sql

How would the following compare in performance to see whether the ID I have is in a set.

```
# python list
list_of_ids = [1,2,3,...]
if id in list_of_ids:
    # ok

# python set
set_of_ids = set([1,2,3,...])
if id in set_of_ids:
    # ok

# python dict
dict_of_ids = {1:,2:,3:,...}
if id in dict_of_ids:
    # ok

# SQL
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = %s, id)
if cursor.fetchone():

// in C
# [ not written]
```

How would these compare?

Comment: I have no idea about python (or how it can even be compared to sql, for that matter), but your SQL query would be better off as `Select 1` rather than `Select *` if you just want to know existence.

Comment: Assuming that the goal is really to figure out whether a particular ID exists in a database table or a set of rows, this question is too vague to answer in isolation. In cases where the performance of such an operation really matters, there are usually ways to optimize it, but they are highly dependent on the surrounding context of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithmically speaking, the first approach took linear both time and space `O(n)`.

the second and the third approach uses `HASH table` runs faster than `O(log(n))`

And the SQL approach uses B-tree, if an index was on that field, its time complexity is `O(log(n))`.

If you use C, it save some time because the C language skip many non-efficient part.

---

**Conclusion:**

1. The first approach took O(n) time and memory cost, better not use it.
2. The second and third one is fast enought, but if the data is too large, it will be slow.
3. The SQL approach may cost network communicating time, so it has other part cost, but if the data is large, I think the SQL way will be more reasonable.
4. The C approach is extremely fast, if you **REALLY** need it (of course, the algorithm it use must be efficient), and that would make the code ugly anyway.

Hope it helps.